# Does android reuse views during a orientation change

Tags: android

Does android reuse views during a orientation change?
I have a progress bar in my activity. I set the progress to 50%, and then do an orientation change. But for some reason, the progress bar maintain 50% after the orientation.  I have call setprogress(0) in the onCreate() of my activity. And I have put 'printf' in anywhere I call setProgress(), i don't still don't understand why the progress bar maintains 50% everytime I do an orientation change?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity gets torn down and recreated, but Views with IDs set save their instance state to pass through to their future selves after they are recreated. This is restored in [`onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). Since `onRestoreInstanceState` is called after `onCreate`, the value you set in `onCreate` is overwritten by the previously saved data.

If you want to manipulate your views after this step happens, [`onPostCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) may be what you're looking for.

If you'd like to know more about how this process works (potentially to implement this save/restore behavior in your own custom views), see [`View#onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and [`View#onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are supressing the `onCreate` method on a configuration change for the configuration including `orientation/keyboardHidden` in your `manifest` file.  remove the `android:configChanges` from your activity in the manifest XML, and remove the `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method from your activity.

Or, just set the progress of the progressbar to 0 in your `onConfigurationChanged` method

if you are implementing the `onConfigurationChanged` method, make sure you have it defined in the manifest XML file for the desired activity.

for example:

```
<activity
      android:name="MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

`onConfigurationChanged` will then be called when orientation or keyboardHidden configurations occur

Comment: i have over-loaded onConfigurationChanged method in my activity, but it never gets called.  I don't have any android:configChanges in my manifest xml file.

Comment: OKay, but I want the onCreate() to be called whenever an orientation change occurred. I don't have android:configChanges in my Manifest file. and I don't have onConfigurationChanged method. And I do have setProgress(0) in my onCreate(), why the progress bar is **not** empty when there is an orientation change?

Comment: add the relevant code and manifest to your question so maybe we can take a visual look at whats going on!